# Tracing root cause for R segfault

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm working on a quite complicated dashboard written in R using Shiny and ggplot2.

At the moment it was written everything worked fine, but after some time (data is updated daily) it started to segfault while rendering specific pages.

I can reproduce the problem by opening specific tab with 12 ggplot graphs.

Console output at the moment of failure looks like this:

```
dashboard_1 | address 0x194b1, cause 'memory not mapped'
dashboard_1 | 
dashboard_1 | Traceback:
dashboard_1 |  1: mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
dashboard_1 |  2: Map(build_grob, plot$layer, data)
dashboard_1 |  3: ggplot_gtable(data)
dashboard_1 |  4: print.ggplot(result$value)
dashboard_1 |  5: print(result$value)
dashboard_1 |  6: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
dashboard_1 |  7: eval(expr, pf)
dashboard_1 |  8: withVisible(eval(expr, pf))
dashboard_1 |  9: evalVis(expr)
dashboard_1 | 10: capture.output(print(result$value))
...
dashboard_1 | 65: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
dashboard_1 | 66: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
dashboard_1 | 67: tryCatch(evalq((function (handle, binary, message) {    for    (handler in .wsconns[[as.character(handle)]]$.messageCallbacks) {        result <- try(handler(binary, message))        if (inherits(result, "try-error")) {            .wsconns[[as.character(handle)]]$close()            return()        }    }})("62978544", FALSE, "{\"method\":\"update\",\"data\":{\"daterange:shiny.date\":[\"2014-04-26\",\"2015-04-26\"],\"group_by\":\"weeks\"}}"),     <environment>), error = .rcpp_error_recorder)
dashboard_1 | 68: withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(evalq((function (handle, binary,     message) {    for (handler in .wsconns[[as.character(handle)]]$.messageCallbacks) {        result <- try(handler(binary, message))        if (inherits(result, "try-error")) {            .wsconns[[as.character(handle)]]$close()            return()        }    }})("62978544", FALSE, "{\"method\":\"update\",\"data\":{\"daterange:shiny.date\":[\"2014-04-26\",\"2015-04-26\"],\"group_by\":\"weeks\"}}"),     <environment>), error = .rcpp_error_recorder), warning = .rcpp_warning_recorder)
dashboard_1 | aborting ...
dashboard_1 | Segmentation fault
rmreports_dashboard_1 exited with code 139
```

I would like to trace the root cause and introduce changes to prevent segfault from happening. What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Can you reproduce this outside of shiny? That might point to a ggplot bug. Anyway, debugging stuff at the C code level is very OS-dependent and you don't mention your operating system (or R version...)

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to reproduce bug executing ggplots one by one in RStudio it seems like the bug is a collaboration of shiny and ggplot. I was able to reproduce issue both on MacOS X (dev) and on Ubuntu 14.10 (prod).

Answer (score 1):

I was searching your problem was able to find this thread. https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/322
Which says to try to update 'dplyr' with 'devtools'.
"devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr", build_vignettes = FALSE)"

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use this approach to ggplot2, see if it works